# How to change values of keys of an object having same value without mutation while keeping reference of unchanged keys the same in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux

I have an object like this:

```js
const obj1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value1}
```

I want to change the value of all keys having value `value1` to `value3`:

```js
// obj2
{key1: value3, key2: value2, key3: value3}
```

Basically, my values are another objects. 
I do not want to create new instances of the unchanged values.
And, I do not want to mutate the original object `obj1`.

---

#### EDIT

My reason is that keeping the reference same would prevent me unnecessary re-renders.
[see this tweet for details](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/688087202312491008)

I don't know how to give example on this, all I can say is that, if the value of the key has to be changed, return new value, otherwise return old value, do not assign old value.

Comment: you could use `let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1)` to make a clone if the object

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: Could you provide and example of `value1` and `value3` ?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the entries, look for the wanted value and replace this value. Then build a new object.

```js
const
    source = { key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 1 },
    search = 1,
    replace = 3,
    target = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(source)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v === search ? replace : v])
    );

console.log(target);
```